# Восстановление текста после сбоя

Tags: восстановление

Пользователь работал более трех часов в MSWord2007, после чего возникла ошибка и произошел выброс из программы, данные сохранились некорректно.
За 3 часа напечатано было много, очень много, поэтому как-то надо восстановить.
Автосохранение было настроено.
При сбое перед выбросом из программы создались файлы: 
~$1.docx
~1.tmp
ну и соответственно, уже существовал файл 1.docx, но страно, что даже он теперь не открывается нормально.
Если нельзя восстановить последние изменения, то можно ли хотя бы восстановить те данные, которые были в этом доке перед трехчасовой работой?

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще попробовать в самом ворде начать открывать файл, и в кнопке Открыть выбрать меню Открыть и восстановить

Answer (score 0):

в интернете много программ для восстановления данных из программы MW.
Вот первая попавшаяся на заметку: Recovery Toolbox for Word